# Differences between OOP principles and OOP concepts?

Tags: java, oop

I have this confusion on Object Oriented Programming. I have to answer some question for some code that I wrote:

1. What are the OOP principles used in this code?
2. How have been they applied?
3. Explain the OOP concepts used in this code.

Here I don't understand the differences between these 2 words 'principles' and 'concepts'. Are they same? Or different?

I know there are 4 object oriented principles.

1. Inheritance.
2. Abstraction
3. Encapsulation.
4. Polymorphism.

And in my code I have setter methods, getter methods, abstract class, inheritance betweens classes. So I answer like this:

1. Inheritance, Abstraction, Encapsulation, Polymorphism.
2. I used setter methods, getter methods, abstract class, inheritance betweens classes. And that's how it was applied.
3. I don't know.

Here is the confusion. Do I have to explain:

- Inheritance, Abstraction, Encapsulation, Polymorphism?

  or
- methods, getter methods, abstract class, inheritance between classes?

Comment: I think u should explain the getter methods, abstract class, inheritance between classes

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 major principles of OOP , Encapsulation, Data Abstraction, Polymorphism and Inheritance. These are also called as four pillars of Object Oriented Programming.

The OOP concepts are Class, Object, Inheritance, Interface and Package.

I was also confused in this until my teacher told me that, principles are the set of rules, which you have to apply and concept is the understanding of how you can apply those rules.

Therefore, one can understand what has to be done , from the principles and how that should be done or in what field that should be done , through the concept.

I hope i have been able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider doing this  - you may not give theoretical explanation of Inheritance, Abstraction, Encapsulation, Polymorphism. You should mention what advantages these OOP principals are giving in your overall class design, code flow and the reason why you applied them.